# Strange result with .where using LIKE operator in PySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, where-clause

I am having a `PySpark` DataFrame, and I wish to keep only those `IDs` which  begin with 5 or 6 **AND** have length 5. I have taken `IDs` as strings.

```
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame([('51087',),('61211',),('09112',),('521',),],("ID",))
df.show()
+-----+
|   ID|
+-----+
|51087|
|61211|
|09112|
|  521|
+-----+

df=df.where((col("ID").like('5%') | col("ID").like('6%')) & (length(col("ID"))==5))
df.show()
#I get the right answer.
+-----+
|   ID|
+-----+
|51087|
|61211|
+-----+
```

But, if I use the following code, which involves both SQL (former) and DataFrame (later) styled conditions, I get wrong result -

```
df=df.where(("ID like '5%' or ID like '6%'") and (length(col("ID"))==5))
df.show()
#Wrong result
+-----+
|   ID|
+-----+
|51087|
|61211|
|09112|
+-----+
```

Not only that, if I used **OR** operator instead of **AND** operator, I again get wrong result.

```
df=df.where(("ID like '5%' or ID like '6%'") or (length(col("ID"))==5))
df.show()
#Again wrong result
+-----+
|   ID|
+-----+
|51087|
|61211|
|  521|
+-----+
```

Now, this is just counter intuitive. The result which I expect with **AND** operator, I get with **OR** operator and vice versa. Let me construct a truth table of both conditions respectively. Can anyone explain this fallacy?

```
Truth Table
condition1 condition2    AND    OR
True       True         True    True
True       True         True    True
False      True         False   True
True       False        False   True
```

Comment: `("ID like '5%' or ID like '6%'") and (length(col("ID"))==5)` does not do what you think it does. You need to `import pyspark.sql.functions.expr` and do something like `where(expr("ID like '5%' or ID like '6%'") &(length(col("ID"))==5))`. (Notice the bitwise operator between the columns (don't use `and` or `or`).

Comment: Oh, then my understanding is fallacious. I must research this issue afresh. Your code works perfectly. Thank you pault for your help. Very appreciated :)